# Easy to repair washing machine?

Tags: appliances

It appears our front loading Kenmore (aka Whirlpool) may need new main bearings, and various sources (including appliance repair guy and online reading) suggest that replacing them is a non-trivial job and "best to just replace the whole thing". (Btw, this failure was most likely caused by the machine not being properly leveled which caused excessive shaking during the spin cycle.  Something for others to learn from my mistake!)

Assuming I do need to replace it, I'd rather buy one that is easier to repair in the future. I don't mind if its an older model (though I definitely prefer a front loader). It doesn't need all the fancy electronic features (more to go wrong!).

Can anyone recommend a category or brand of machine that is better than others?

E.g. I wonder if some of the laundromat machines are better, as they have to hold their own in a pretty tough commercial environment?

Comment: This is a little tangential, but I wasn't aware that Kenmore's were just re-branded Whirlpools. Interestingly, our Whirlpool's quality has been great -- no issues whatsoever, but more than one friend's Kenmore has failed. Anyone know what the quality differences are with these? Did I just get lucky with my Whirlpool?

Comment: @andrew flanagan: I just had to have my washing machine replaced.  According to my repairman (who is a family friend) he said Kenmore and Whirlpool are the same thing and only buy those.  He did list 1 other brand (which is also a rebranded Whirlpool) but I forgot what it was.

Comment: Not sure if should be posting this as a possible answer or a comment, but I emailed a friend of mine who owns a small apartment building which has a coin laundry and he responded:

When I ask my appliance guy he says they are all much the same in whatever price range you're at. I think it is pretty much "you get what you pay for." I would avoid Simplicity stackers (hard to service, in spite of the name!)

Maybe even look at Huebsch or GE Commercial. They work day in and out in my apartment shared laundry but be careful you have the right voltage/phase if you go that route.

Comment: A lot of appliance shopping is about buying a particular logo on the same machine more than one company is selling.

Comment: This question seems to be asking for shopping advice, and will likely solicit answers that are primarily opinion based. It's also very likely that the answers will become outdated fairly quickly.  The best, most reliable manufacturers make mistakes from time to time. It's best to research individual machines, rather than manufacturers.

Comment: @AndrewFlanagan - Yes, most Kenmore product as far as washers and dryers go is produced by Whirlpool. Neither a good nor a bad thing and it always meant we could easily find parts.

Answer (score 2):

**Staber** advertises that you can do the repairs yourself, and they will sell you parts and give free phone support.

Some people love them (low water, low power, low soap, gentle on clothes, spins out more water, built in USA, great customer service)

Other people hate them (expensive, loud, bad customer service).

Search the web and read both the rants and raves.